# Как правильно глобально отловить событие Alt+PrintScreen и PrintScreen?

Tags: c#, winapi

Не могу отловить:
1-ое из указанных событий;
2-ое вроде бы ловлю, но в буфере не всегда есть скриншот.

Подскажите или приведите пример.

Comment: в отдельном потоке надо вызывать [GetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx) и проверять что нажато.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что скриншот в буфере обмена образуется не просто так - а такой же программой, которая ловит эти комбинации клавиш и кладет скриншот туда. Поэтому следить за нажатием этой комбинации клавиш и ждать скриншота в буфере - не лучшая идея.

Возможных нормальных вариантов решения - два.

Во-первых, можно делать скриншот самому, в этом поможет функция [`CopyFromScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen(v=vs.110).aspx)

Во-вторых, можно наблюдать за буфером обмена и ждать, пока там появится картинка. Для этого понадобится функция WINAPI [`AddClipboardFormatListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Я накопал кое-что на эту тему, но не совсем понимаю как этим воспользоваться в моем приложении. Можете помочь ?